# Semicolon and Single Quotation in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

The following UNLOAD:

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT "Field1" from "XX"."XX" where "Field1" = \'String\';')
TO 'XXX'
IAM_ROLE 'XXX'
DELIMITER AS ','
ADDQUOTES
ESCAPE 
NULL AS ''
MANIFEST
```

causes the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: unterminated quoted string at or near "'SELECT "Field1" from "XX"."XX" where "Field1" = \'String\'";
```

It seems to be the combination of the escaped single quotes and the semicolon. Since this works:

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT "Field1" from "XX"."XX" where "Field1" = \'String\'')
TO 'XXX'
IAM_ROLE 'XXX'
DELIMITER AS ','
ADDQUOTES
ESCAPE 
NULL AS ''
MANIFEST
```

and this works:

```
 UNLOAD ('SELECT "Field1" from "XX"."XX" where "Field1" = "Field2";')
 TO 'XXX'
 IAM_ROLE 'XXX'
 DELIMITER AS ','
 ADDQUOTES
 ESCAPE 
 NULL AS ''
 MANIFEST
```

I was wondering if anyone has seen anything about this. Haven't found the answer via https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

Comment: What is your actual problem? Normally, there should be no need to quote field or table names unless they contain Uppercase letters. String values are normally delimited by double-quotes in SQL anyway.

Comment: Why are you using backslashes to escape the single quotes in the select statement? What is the literal string you're trying to compare to in the where clause?

Comment: The actual string literal is 'String', ie that can be any String, 
In the following documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html you can see that I should be able to escape a single quote as long as ESCAPE is specified in the UNLOAD command

Comment: It looks like it may be a bug:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=174276